# ¿Por qué no me reconoce el array en el for?

Tags: javascript

El objetivo era crear un objeto que se pudiera dar un imprimir por consola de cada elemento del array que se encuentra arriba, no. importa el formato sino que simplemente en un console.log simple lo hiciera

```js
//Aqui se crea el objeto
let singleCar = [ 
    { 
    casa: "BMW" ,
    modelo: "1995" ,
    marca: "M3"
    } ,
    { 
    casa: "Mercedes Benz" ,
    modelo: "2020" ,
    marca: "AM5"
    },
    { 
    casa: "Ford" ,
    modelo: "2006" ,
    marca: "Mustang GT"
    }
];

//Aqui la función para imprimir en consola cada uno de los elementos.

function callObject (singleCar) {
    return singleCar.forEach(car => {
        console.log(singleCar[car]);
    });
} ;


callObject(singleCar);
```

Comment: por que `car` es cada uno de esos objetos. haz un `console.log(car)` y veras a lo que me refiero

Comment: La *convención de nombre* es MUY importante. Como bien dice @Christian `car` es cada uno de tus objetos ... y llamar al parámetro de la función `singleCar` crea una confusión enorme, porque eso no es un  objeto simple, aquí `singleCar` es en ralidad **todos los car** y debería llamarse `allCars`  o parecido. La realidad del código es esa: la función está recibiendo todos los car, los cuales recorres en un bucle. Por otra parte, si vas a imprimir dentro de la función el `return` no tiene ningún sentido aquí.

Answer (score 3):

### Solución

Lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```js
let singleCar = [ 
    { 
    casa: "BMW" ,
    modelo: "1995" ,
    marca: "M3"
    } ,
    { 
    casa: "Mercedes Benz" ,
    modelo: "2020" ,
    marca: "AM5"
    },
    { 
    casa: "Ford" ,
    modelo: "2006" ,
    marca: "Mustang GT"
    }
];

//Aqui la función para imprimir en consola cada uno de los elementos.

function callObject (singleCar) {
    return singleCar.forEach(car => {
        console.log(car);
    });
} ;


callObject(singleCar);
```

En vez de hacer `console.log(singleCar[car])` dentro del `foreach` debes hacer `console.log(car)`

---

### Explicación

Esto es así porque la funcion [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) ejecuta la funcion que le envías por cada elemento del arreglo y le pasa a dicha funcion el elemento en sí.

Otra opción es recibir otro parametro en la función que envías que hará de indice:

```js
    let singleCar = [ 
        { 
        casa: "BMW" ,
        modelo: "1995" ,
        marca: "M3"
        } ,
        { 
        casa: "Mercedes Benz" ,
        modelo: "2020" ,
        marca: "AM5"
        },
        { 
        casa: "Ford" ,
        modelo: "2006" ,
        marca: "Mustang GT"
        }
    ];

    //Aqui la función para imprimir en consola cada uno de los elementos.

    function callObject (singleCar) {
        return singleCar.forEach((car, index) => {
            console.log(singleCar[index]);
        });
    } ;


    callObject(singleCar);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo el problema era que no estaba llamando de manera correcta el objeto, (no sabía como usar bien el forEach)

Comment: Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema considera marcarla como respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás recorriendo es el array de car, por lo tanto, deberías llamar a la función car y no al objeto que te da la función singleCar.

```
function callObject (singleCar) {
return singleCar.forEach(car => {
    console.log(car);
});
```

} ;

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, tienes toda la razón